# Submitting data from template to controller in symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, submit

Is there any way in Symfony2 to submit data from a template to a controller apart from using forms?

Comment: You could submit static data ... but your going to be hard pressed to find a solution even in PHP to submit dynamic data without using forms ....

Comment: the problem is I would like to submit a variable that gets its value from a Jquery function inside the template and I dont see how to do it using forms. Any idea @ManseUK ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a hidden input :

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenval" name="hiddenval" value=""/>
```

jQuery :

```
$('#hiddenval').val('your new value');
```

Then when the form is submitted you can get the value ...

[Here are the docs for creating a hidden field in Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/hidden.html)

Comment: Could you please give me an example of how the controller action and the template would look like in this case @ManseUK? Thank you very much. I am a newbie in Symfony.

Comment: @Haritz there are some good examples here -> http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

Comment: I tried to do what yo said. This is the problem I am getting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600205/http-status-code-in-form-submission-symfony2 , Any idea @ManseUK? Thnaks.